# SaltStack and PaaS

Tags: heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-web-roles, paas, salt-stack

Is Salt suited for PaaS?

Let's say I'd like to provision a PaaS compute service, such as Amazon BeanStalk, Azure Cloud Service (web role / worker role), or even a Heroku Dyno, as part of an SaltStack state (perhaps besides a VM or a database). Each of these services contain an API and some an SDK, meaning that it should technically be possible for the master to provision the PaaS using a (Python) script.

Of course, SaltStack is primarily written for IaaS. However, is the above use case common/possible for SaltStack?

Comment: You can use Salt for PaaS/IaaS/bare metal/anything. FYI we are using Salt as our configuration management tools for all our instances and services in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: If it has an API, Salt can talk to it.

Long answer:

There are currently no built in execution modules or states for provisioning Amazon Beanstalk, Azure Cloud Service*, or Heroku. That said, there's no reason there could not be. See, for example, the suite of boto_* execution modules and states (search for "boto_*" on http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/). Such state modules could be used in your state SLSs and execution modules could be called from a custom runner.

*I'm not personally familiar with the Azure platform or salt-cloud, but salt-cloud does support Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Every PaaS services usually have API supports in multiple languages. Using Python for example, you can create modules to do the needful and call modules from salt states as required.